# Writing files using spark and reading using python

Tags: python, pandas

writing a file s3  using  spark usually creates a directory with 11 files success and the other file name starts with name as part which has actual data in s3 , how to load the same file using pandas dataframe since the file path changes because the file name Par for all 10 files with actual data varies in each run.

For example the file path at the time of writing :

```
df.colaesce.(10).write.path("s3://testfolder.csv")
```

The files stored in the directory are :

```
- sucess
- part-00-*.parquet
```

I have a python job which reads the file to pandas dataframe

```
pd.read(s3\\..........what is the path to specify here.................)
```

Comment: I haven't found the relation between the question and pyspark, so I changed the tags.

Comment: Files are being written by Pyspark so added t

Answer (score 0):

when writing files with spark, you cannot pass the name the file (you can, but you end up with what you described above). if you want a single file to later load to pandas, you would do something like this:

```
df.repartition(1).write.parquet(path="s3://testfolder/", mode='append')
```

The end result will be a single file in "s3://testfolder/" that starts with **part-00-*.parquet**. You can simply read that file in or rename the file to something specific before reading it in with pandas.

Comment: Yes even i tried that but when we go for writing large file will repartition (1) won't hit memory issues ,if i remove that then multiple files will be created how to load those in single pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: (Recommended)

You can use **awswrangler**. Its a light weight tool to aid with the integration between
Pandas/S3/Parquet. It lets you read in multiple files from the directory.

```
pip install awswrangler

import awswrangler as wr

df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path='s3://testfolder/')
```

Option 2:

```
############################## RETRIEVE KEYS FROM THE BUCKET ##################################

import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

s3_bucket_name = 'your bucket name'
prefix = 'path where the files are located'

response = s3.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket = s3_bucket_name, 
    Prefix = prefix 
)

keys = []
for obj in response['Contents']:
    keys.append(obj['Key'])
    
##################################### READ IN THE FILES  ####################################### 


df=[]
for key in keys:
    df.append(pd.read_parquet(path = 's3://' + s3_bucket_name + '/' + key, engine = 'pyarrow'))
```